# Who is God referencing in 1 Chronicles 17:13?

Tags: hebrew, prophecy, 1-chronicles

Regarding the Ivri (עִבְרִי) / Hebrew (ἑβραιου) text of 1 Chronicles 17:13 - God reveals a message about 2 individuals to the prophet Nathan (Natan, נָתָ֖ן).

**1 Chronicles 17:13 [MT]**

> "I shall be to him as a Father, and he will be to Me as a Son, but I will not withdraw My Favor from him as I withdrew [it] from-whom was before-you." (אֲנִי֙ אֶֽהְיֶה־לּ֣וֹ לְאָ֔ב וְה֖וּא יִֽהְיֶה־לִּ֣י לְבֵ֑ן וְחַסְדִּי֙ לֹֽא־אָסִ֣יר מֵֽעִמּ֔וֹ כַּֽאֲשֶׁ֣ר הֲסִיר֔וֹתִי מֵֽאֲשֶׁ֥ר הָיָ֖ה לְפָנֶֽיךָ)

1. **Who is God's future Son?**

> "I shall be to him as a Father" (אֲנִי֙ אֶֽהְיֶה־לּ֣וֹ לְאָ֔ב)

> "and he will be to Me as a Son" (וְה֖וּא יִֽהְיֶה־לִּ֣י לְבֵ֑ן)

2. **Who is the Predecessor that lost God's favor?**

> "but-My-favor shall Not-withdraw from him" (וְחַסְדִּי֙ לֹֽא־אָסִ֣יר מֵֽעִמּ֔וֹ)

> "as-I withdrew [it] from-whom was before-you" (כַּֽאֲשֶׁ֣ר הֲסִיר֔וֹתִי מֵֽאֲשֶׁ֥ר הָיָ֖ה לְפָנֶֽיךָ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Who is the predecessor that lost God's favor?

David's immediate predecessor was Saul. He lost God's favor:

> 1 Samuel 15:27 As Samuel turned to leave, Saul caught hold of the hem of his robe, and it tore. 28Samuel said to him, “The Lord has torn the kingdom of Israel from you today and has given it to one of your neighbors—to one better than you.

Who is God's future Son?

> 1 Chronicles 17:11 When your days are over and you go to be with your ancestors, I will raise up your offspring to succeed you, one of your own sons, and I will establish his kingdom. 12 He is the one who will **build a house for me**, and I will establish his throne forever. 13
> I will be his father, and he will be my son. I will never take my love away from him, as I took it away from your predecessor.

The prophecy of the future son was fulfilled immediately in Solomon:

> 1 Kings 5:2 Solomon sent back this message to Hiram:
> 3“You know that because of the wars waged against my father David from all sides, he could not build a temple for the Name of the Lord his God until the Lord put his enemies under his feet. 4But now the Lord my God has given me rest on every side, and there is no adversary or disaster. 5 **I intend, therefore, to build a temple for the Name of the Lord my God**, as the Lord told my father David, when he said, ‘Your son whom I will put on the throne in your place will build the temple for my Name.’

Solomon himself was well aware of the prophecy and knew he was part of this history. However, there was a long-term perfect fulfillment of this prophecy. Jesus fulfilled it.

Jesus was son of David. Matthew 1:1

> A record of the genealogy of Jesus Christ the **son of David**, the son of Abraham.

Jesus was the King of the Jews. Matthew 2:1,2

> Now after Jesus was born in Bethlehem of Judea in the days of Herod the king, magi from the east arrived in Jerusalem, saying, "Where is he who has been born **King of the Jews**? For we saw his star in the east and have come to worship him"

Jesus' body is the spiritual temple of God.

> John 2:19 Jesus answered them, “Destroy this temple, and I will raise it again in three days.”
> 20 They replied, “It has taken forty-six years to build this temple, and you are going to raise it in three days?” 21 But **the temple he had spoken of was his body**.

Today, Christians are members of this Body of Christ.